# Firebase logout not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase authentication with google accounts. Login process works fine, but I have a problem with logout. Everything seems fine when user clicks "logout" button, but when "login" button is clicked after logout, the previously signed in user is loged in automaticaly - no prompt for credentials. That happens even in incognito mode.

This is the code i'm using. All the communication with Firebase services happens here:

```html
function auth() { 
 // Initialize Firebase;
 firebase.initializeApp(settings);
 var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
 
 firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  sessionStorage.setItem('tokenK', token);
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
  var tempName = user.displayName.split(" ");
  var fullName = tempName[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + tempName[0].toLowerCase().substring(1, tempName[0].length) + 
  " " + tempName[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() +tempName[1].toLowerCase().substring(1, tempName[1].length);
  sessionStorage.setItem('displayName', fullName);
  sessionStorage.setItem('userName', user.email);
 }).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
  console.log(error);
 });
}
```

```
function logOut(){  
    firebase.initializeApp(settings);
    var dataJ = JSON.stringify(sessionStorage.getItem('userName'));
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 204) {
                sessionStorage.removeItem('tokenK');
                sessionStorage.removeItem('displayName');
                sessionStorage.removeItem('userName');
                sessionStorage.removeItem('role');
                sessionStorage.removeItem('school');
                sessionStorage.removeItem('grade');
                window.open('index.html', '_self');                 
            }                   
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", settings.protocol + "://" + settings.host + ":" + settings.port + "/api/Login/SignOut", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Token", sessionStorage.getItem('tokenK'));  
        xhttp.send(dataJ);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }); 
}
```

What can be the problem here?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are going through the .signOut() success path?  If, after the .signOut() has completed successfully does firebase.auth() still return a logged in user object?  (i.e. are you sure the logout was successful?). It might also help to show your login code, perhaps there's a problem there.

Comment: Why are you calling initializeApp during logout?  That's typically something you do once when the page first loads.  It doesn't make sense call it ever again after that point.

Comment: @DougStevenson Because if I don't initialize it again, nothing works at all.

Comment: @joelm The proccess goes through successful path, I see taht sessionStorage becomes clean. Same about loclaStorage.

I've added the login code so you can see what happens from the beggining.

Comment: You should only have to call initializeApp once per page load.  Anything else is not correct.

Comment: @DougStevenson But how and where should I do it? If I initialize it on the load page, I cna't use it one other pages. If I initialize it on every page I load, it causes the same problem from where we started.

Comment: It should be initialized exactly once on each page load.

Comment: @DougStevenson I initialize it only when user clicks login or logout. It happens on different pages. I don't get what is the right way to do it.

Comment: Every official sample that you can observe initializes unconditionally as the very beginning of the page.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ok, I've did what you said. I initialize the app on load of all the pages and not on click. Yet again, the same outcome - login details are saved until i close the tab..

Comment: Try contacting Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for the advices

Comment: try this :

var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({
  prompt: 'select_account'
});

Answer (score 4):

I tried this and worked for me.

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({
  prompt: 'select_account'
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was looking for this for two days!

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got it. Working in cordova :

***You need to logout the googlePlus as well***. Please try below :

```
doLogout(){
    var promise =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(firebase.auth().currentUser){
        this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
        if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
          this.googlePlus.logout();
        }
        resolve(true);
      }
      else {
        reject();
      }
    });
    return promise;    }
```

----------**And for website try below :** ----

```
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(); 

provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
```